# Loading layer into QGIS via Python

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I am trying to load in a layer to QGIS via Python but a weird "unicode error" - message appears. Dont know what that message means nor what the problem is.

Do any of you know?

[image]

Comment: What do you see at the positions 2-3 in your file path string? What do you find on StackOverflow if you search this exact error message?

Comment: Check this ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Comment: My filepath string is: "C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Open_Source_kartografi\Labb4\NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp" so position 2-3 is just  :\

Comment: maybe the backslash is wrongturned?  should it be :/ and not :\ ?

Comment: But i mean the filepath is copied so it should not be that

Comment: please don't post screenshots of text/error messages - it breaks screen readers

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a raw python string: prepend the string with `r` such as this:

```py
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\my\path")
```

or escape every `\` such as this:

```py
lyr = QgsVectorLayer("C:\\my\\path")
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. now i got another error saying that QgsMapLayerRegistry Does not exist

Comment: NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined